# Could not find a part of the path during File.Copy

Tags: vb.net, file-copying

I'm trying to copy a file to another directory but I'm getting this error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\(my username)\Desktop\Source_Folder\File_1.xlsx'.

But File_1.xlsx exists in the folder Source_Folder which exists on my Desktop. So why am I getting this error?

Here is my code

```
    Dim path_orig As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\(my username)\Desktop\Source_Folder\"
    Dim oldFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(path_orig, filename)
    Dim path_new As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\Destination_Folder\"
    Dim newFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(path_new, filename)
    File.Copy(oldFile, newFile, True)
```

*filename is a variable which in this case is "File_1.xlsx"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hard code `Documents and Settings`.  It will change by OS.  Use this instead:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Source_Folder")
```

Also if you're running this in a web application you're likely running into permissions problems.  Change the location where you're storing files and/or change the user the app pool is running under and/or grant the app pool user rights to the folder.

Comment: Hey thanks. I did what you said but I'm getting this error now `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\(my username)\Desktop\Source_Folder\File_1.xlsx'.`

Comment: @Artemis, use Process Monitor to see what error is being generated internally.  If it's an access violation this will tell you what user is trying to access it too.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx